# Create Workbook with variable name vba

Tags: excel, vba

Maybe this is a stupid question, but I can't figure it out. I am trying to create a workbook in vba. I have a code that creates a file folder depending on the name of a textbox, and I want it to create a workbook with the same name, saved in that folder.  This is my code so far:

```
Private Sub cmdok_Click()
    Dim name As String
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim file As String

    If frmnewproject.txtname.Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "You must include a name"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    name = frmnewproject.txtname.Value
    sPath = "P:\Projects\" & name


    If Len(Dir(sPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir sPath
        Workbooks.Add.SaveAs filename:= sPath&"\" &name& ".xlsx"

    Else
        MsgBox "That Project folder already exists"
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `sPath & "\" & name & ".xlsx"`

Comment: Thank you, that worked!